# SKScene in landscape gives wrong UITouch coordinates when scene is presented second time

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am having an issue getting the correct coordinates from a `UITouch` on an `SKScene` after the `SKScene` is presented the second time.  I've written a simplified app to demonstrate the issue located here:

https://github.com/JenDobson/SKSceneCoordinatesIssue

In this simplified app there is 1 scene.  The scene has a single SKNode.  When the scene is touched, if the `UITouch` location intersects with the `SKNode`, the `touchesEnded:withEvent` method calls back to the ViewController to present the scene a second time.  But when the scene is presented a second time, when I attempt to touch the `SKNode`, the coordinates of the UITouch are reversed (i.e. the x value reports the y value and vice versa).  They thus don't intersect with the `SKNode`, and the scene is not presented again.  (If I touch at the location on the screen that is the `SKNode's` position reflected over the line x=y, then I can get the scene to be presented again.)

I've tried playing around with "ViewWillLayoutSubviews", but in this sample app the view is only loaded once, so I believe that `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` is not called repeatedly and therefore cannot affect the scene coordinates.

To illustrate the issue, here is the output from `touchesEnded:withEvent` the first time the scene is presented:

```
2014-07-21 17:57:06.908 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] scene frame size:1024.000000,768.000000
2014-07-21 17:57:06.911 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] location:685.000000,105.500000
2014-07-21 17:57:06.912 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] navNode Position:700.000000,100.000000
```

And here is the output from touchesEnded:withEvent the second time the scene is presented:

```
2014-07-21 17:57:14.724 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] scene frame size:1024.000000,768.000000
2014-07-21 17:57:14.725 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] location:107.000000,632.500000
2014-07-21 17:57:14.726 TestTouchCoordinatesInSKScene[5476:60b] navNode Position:700.000000,100.000000
```

Note that "location" has the x- and y- coordinates reversed for the second listing.

Below is what I think the relevant code is.

In "MyViewController.m"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    SKView* skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width,skView.bounds.size.height);

    _mainMenuScene = [MyMainMenuScene sceneWithSize:contentSize];
    _mainMenuScene.controller = self;
    _mainMenuScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;


    [skView presentScene:_mainMenuScene];

}


-(void)loadView
{
    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
    SKView* view = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    self.view = view;
}

-(void)returnToMainMenu
{
    [(SKView*)self.view presentScene:_mainMenuScene transition:[SKTransition moveInWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionRight duration:.3]];

}
@end
```

In "MyMainMenuScene.m"

```
-(CGPoint)navNodePosition
{
    return CGPointMake(700,100);
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        _navNode = [SKLabelNode node];
        _navNode.position = [self navNodePosition];
        _navNode.text = @"Return to Main Menu";
        _setupLabel.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _setupLabel.fontSize = 24;

        [self addChild:_navNode];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    BOOL shouldSegueToMainMenu = NO;

    NSLog(@"scene frame size:%f,%f",self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height);


    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        NSLog(@"location:%f,%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
        NSLog(@"navNode Position:%f,%f",self.navNode.position.x,self.navNode.position.y);


        if ([self.navNode containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
            shouldSegueToMainMenu = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (shouldSegueToMainMenu)
    {
        [self.controller returnToMainMenu];
    }

}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around more, I believe this is a bug in the `SKView` method `presentScene:transition`.  In the `returnToMainMenu` method of `MyViewController`, if I use the plain old `presentScene` method rather than `presentScene:transition`, the problem goes away.  I've filed this with Apple as bug 17770198.